# React Table renders data undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a React table that is going to be populated by a REST API call.  The following is the output:

```
[{"zone":"Central","location":"Atlantic Superstore","address":"650 Portland St, Dartmouth","date":"05/13/2021","exposure":"09:00 - 11:30","advice":"Get tested immediately"},{"zone":"Central","location":"Sobeys Mumford","address":"6990 Mumford Road, Halifax","date":"31/05/2021","exposure":"13:00 - 14:30","advice":"Get tested Immediately"}]
```

I call it using the following code:

```
export function GetContacts() {
const [loadingData, setLoadingdata] = useState(true);
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
        `https://mz6gux8sca.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/contact`,
        {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        setContacts(response);
        setLoadingdata(false);
     })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}, [])

console.log("contacts: ", contacts)

const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
           Header: "Zone",
           accessor: "zoneID", 
        },
        {
            Header: "Location",
            accessor: "contactLocation",
        },
        {
            Header: "Address",
            accessor: "address",
        },
        {
            Header: "Date",
            accessor: "date",
        },
        {
            Header: "Window",
            accessor: "exposureWindow",
        },
        {
            Header: "Advice",
            accessor: "advice",
        },
    ],
    [],
);
```

Which works, and in the console I get a properly populated contacts list.  However, as soon as I add the following:

```
const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
} = useTable({ columns, contacts }, useSortBy)
```

An error is thrown, and the console output of contacts is empty.  The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. -- presumably because contacts is empty.  If I remove that block, everything goes back to working properly.  I'm at a loss here, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing hook options in wrong way. React Table expects `data` options so `useTable({ columns, data: contacts })` should work.